# substring doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, string, substring

```
getProductType = function (product) {
    var productType = '';
    if (product.standardVariable) {
        productType += 'Standard Variable, ';
    }
    if (product.basic) {
        productType += 'Basic, ';
    }
    if (product.intro) {
        productType += 'Intro, ';
    }
    if (product.fixed) {
        productType += 'Fixed, ';
    }
    if (product.equity) {
        productType += 'Equity';
    } else {
        alert(productType);
        productType.substring(0, productType.length - 2);
        alert(productType);
    }
    return productType;
};
```

My test case is that product.fixed = true, everything else is false.

Why is it that both my alerts print out 'Fixed, '? Why is substring not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Assinging the value to variable because,substring returns a new string.

```
var newstr = productType.substring(0, productType.length - 2);
alert(newstr);
```

Comment: +1, `substring` creates a **copy** out of the original string, doesn't **modify** it

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript. Also, [.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) returns a new string. You'll need to assign the results of the substring to a variable. You can reuse productType for this, so this should do the job:

```
productType = productType.substring(0, productType.length - 2);
```